# How to access and change value of struct members

Tags: c

```
typedef struct
{
    float32                   frequency;     
    Ifx_Priority              isrPriority;  
    IfxSrc_Tos                isrProvider;   
    float32                   minResolution; 
    IfxStdIf_Timer_TrigConfig trigger;      
    float32                   startOffset;   
} IfxStdIf_Timer_Config;

typedef struct
    {
        IfxStdIf_Timer_Config base;                 
        Ifx_GTM              *gtm;                  
        IfxGtm_Tom            tom;                  
        IfxGtm_Tom_Ch         timerChannel;        
        IfxGtm_Tom_ToutMap   *triggerOut;           
        IfxGtm_Tom_Ch_ClkSrc  clock;                
        IfxGtm_IrqMode        irqModeTimer;        
        IfxGtm_IrqMode        irqModeTrigger;       
    } IfxGtm_Tom_Timer_Config;

typedef struct {
            uint32                       size;
            HAL_IF_TIMER_userConfig     *table;
            IfxGtm_Tom_Timer_Config     *defaultSettings;
            } HAL_IF_Tom_Timer_Config;
```

Assign values:

```
HAL_IF_TIMER_userConfig userConfig[NUM_TIMER_CHANNEL] = {
{ 1000, ISR_PRIORITY_1ms_Task, 0, IfxSrc_Tos_cpu0, IfxGtm_Tom_Ch_1, IfxGtm_Tom_Ch_ClkSrc_cmuFxclk1, OneMs, 00 },
{ 5000, ISR_PRIORITY_200us_Critical_Task, 0, IfxSrc_Tos_cpu0, IfxGtm_Tom_Ch_2, IfxGtm_Tom_Ch_ClkSrc_cmuFxclk1, TwoHundredus, 01 },
{ 1, ISR_PRIORITY_1s, 0, IfxSrc_Tos_cpu0, IfxGtm_Tom_Ch_4, IfxGtm_Tom_Ch_ClkSrc_cmuFxclk4, Ones, 02 }

IfxGtm_Tom_Timer_Config defaultTomTimerConfig =
    {{1000, 0, IfxSrc_Tos_cpu0, 0, {FALSE, 0, 0, IfxSrc_Tos_cpu0, IfxPort_OutputMode_pushPull, IfxPort_PadDriver_cmosAutomotiveSpeed1, FALSE, FALSE }, IfxStdIf_Timer_CountDir_up, 0.0}, &MODULE_GTM, IfxGtm_Tom_0, IfxGtm_Tom_Ch_0, NULL_PTR, IfxGtm_Tom_Ch_ClkSrc_cmuFxclk0, IfxGtm_IrqMode_level, IfxGtm_IrqMode_level};

HAL_IF_Tom_Timer_Config TomTimerConfig =
{NUM_TIMER_CHANNEL, userConfig, &defaultTomTimerConfig};

HAL_IF_Tom_Timer_Config g_TomTimerConfig;
```

if i have already assign values to all the struct members, how can i access and change the frequency during runtime?

Runtime:

```
g_TomTimerConfig = TomTimerConfig;
HAL_IF_TIMER_userConfig *userTable = TomTimerConfig.table;
uint32 i;

    for (i = 0; i < g_TomTimerConfig.size; i++, ++userTable) {
        g_TomTimerConfig.defaultSettings->base.frequency = userTable->frequency;
};
```

this part do not work:

```
g_TomTimerConfig->defaultSettings->base->frequency
```

I'm trying to create a default settings and a array of user settings to initialize some settings. thanks in advance

Comment: Please explain what “do not work” means. Compiler errors? Runtime errors? Crashes?

Comment: Do you know the `.` operator?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen if i use g_TomTimerConfig.defaultSettings->base, there is a field 'base' could not be resolved error

Comment: @Yunnosch i tried the . operator too same error

Comment: `g_TomTimerConfig.defaultSettings->base.frequency` assuming that you've actually set things up correctly. If that doesn't work, you'll need to post a [mcve].

Comment: If you work with `->` and `.` by trial and error, I recommend to do some reading. Start with some chapters in your favorite book on `struct` and `pointers`. Then go work on some tutorials on the same topic.

Comment: @user3386109 i have tried that alr also do not work

Comment: @KennyQuahKokSiong I created a [mcve] from your code, compiled it, and ran it. It works just fine, and prints `1000.000000`, which is the correct value.

Answer (score 0):

`g_TomTimerConfig` is a struct, so use `.`

```
g_TomTimerConfig.defaultSettings
```

`defaultSettings` is a pointer to a struct, so use `->`

```
g_TomTimerConfig.defaultSettings->base
```

`base` is a struct, so use `.`

```
g_TomTimerConfig.defaultSettings->base.frequency
```

Comment: What error did you get?  Did you allocate a `IfxGtm_Tom_Timer_Config` struct and point `defaultSettings` to it?